# Can Jssor video slider have Thumbnail navigation?

Tags: javascript, jssor

In the example, video slider is using bullet navigation, I have tried copying Thumbnail navigation codes from 'image-slider-2' in the example folder to the video slider file, but I encountered several problems:

1. I get an error message saying 'thumbnavigator' container height is not set, I have to manually set its height. But what I don't understand is in the example file, it is not required to set the height of thumbnavigator container, why?
2. After I set the height, the videos are working. However, the thumbenail images are not showing, leaving a blank navigation bar.

Is it possible to set thumbnail navigation for the video slider?

Besides, an off-topic question: Can transition effects be applied to video slider?

Answer (score 0):

The video slider is a normal slider which contains a video element in each slide.

Actually, you can place everything you like in any slide.

So, the video slider is fully customizable as well.

Reference:
http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-thumbnail-navigator-jquery.html
http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html